# Data Insert into Multi Set Table Taking High CPU

Tags: teradata

Trying to run a initial bulk load into a Multi Set Table in a split of 10 Insert SQL's based on MOD on Identifier Column. The first and second insert is running but third is failing due to High CPU Skew.

The DBQLOGTBL shows the first SQL took about 10% CPU. The second took 30% and the third was taking 50% CPU hence failed.

The number of records being loaded in each is roughly same. The step which is failing as per the Explain plan is when TD does a MERGE to the main table using Spool.

What could be the solution to solve the problem?

Table is a MULTI SET with NUPI
Partition on a Date Column
Post Initial Load data volume will be 6 TB so roughly 600 GB is being inserted in 10 splits

Comment: *10%* CPU of what, System-CPU, relative to the 3 loads? Those loads were probably no based on the partitioning. But *initial bulk load* means empty table. Why don't you load this table with TPT LOAD in one go?

Comment: 10% Of total Allocated TD System CPU. About 200K AMPCUTIME. The following SQL are taking further more. Yes it is a Empty Table. It is being loaded using another table joined with a GTT having intermediate transformed data. Hence using BTEQ

Comment: I tried bypassing Transient Journal in BTEQ by adding ";" in front of each INSERT and writing all INSERT in sequence. But still after 5-6 INSERT it is failing with CPU TIME issue. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is the table Block Level Compressed? Then the inserts need to un- and recompress all datablocks, if the load is not partition based.